# How to use data returned from subprocess.call without returning the entire output?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
def is_akamaized(url):
    stripped_http_url = url[8:]
    clean_host = stripped_http_url.rsplit('/')[0]
    nslookup_data = subprocess.call(["nslookup", clean_host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if nslookup_data.find('akamaiedge'):
        return "\033[1;31mEnvironment is Acamaized {0}  -  {1}\033[1;m"
```

This function just takes a url and runs nslookup on it.  What I WANT to happen is I want to take the output of nslookup and parse through it for certain keywords.  The problem is, with the current code if I pass in a url that should work (contain the word acamai in the nslookup)

```
print is_acamaized(url)
```

it returns 0

Note, I added the stdout=subprocess.PIPE so that the entire output of nslookup is not returned to the terminal.

Any suggestions on how to assign the output of nslookup to a variable so I can access it?

Comment: Your program should raise an error at `if nslookup_data.find('akamaiedge'):` because `subprocess.call` returns an `int` and `int` doesn't have a `find` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` returns the exit code, not the stdout.  You can use the `Popen` class directly:

```
nslookup_data = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", clean_host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

The `.communicate()[0]` at the end is important.  That tells `Popen` that we are done, and it returns a tuple: (`stdout`, `stderr`).  The first item in the tuple `[0]` is the stdout.

You could also use `subprocess.check_output()`:

```
nslookup_data = subprocess.check_output(["nslookup", clean_host])
```

Comment: is there a reason, not to use `data = check_output("nslookup", clean_host])` here?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That could be done, too.  I added it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It doesn't really help in this case, but you can give it text to go to stdin, and it returns both stdout and stderr as a tuple.